# How to sort a Map in Java by its String keys which are numeric

Tags: java, dictionary

I have created a map called `result`.

In the `sortByKeys` method as my keys are String with Numeric values, I have converted them to Integer key type Map then sorted them.

The sorting is working fine when I am looping and printing individually, but not when I am setting them in another Map.

```
public class TestDate {
    public static void main (String args[]){

    Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();

        result.put("error", "10");
        result.put("1","hii");
        result.put("Update","herii");
        result.put("insert","insert");
        result.put("10","hiiuu");
        result.put("7","hii");
        result.put("21","hii");
        result.put("15","hii"); 

        Map<String, String> sorted = sortByKeys(result);
        //System.out.println(sorted);   
    }

    private static Map<String, String> sortByKeys(Map<String, String> map) {
        Map <Integer,String> unSorted = new  HashMap<Integer, String>();
        Map <String,String> sorted = new  HashMap<String, String>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet())
        {
            try{
                int foo = Integer.parseInt(entry.getKey());            
                unSorted.put(foo, entry.getValue());                
            }catch (Exception e){

            }
        }
        Map<Integer, String> newMap = new TreeMap<Integer, String>(unSorted); 
        Set set = newMap.entrySet();
        Iterator iterator = set.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
            System.out.println(me.getKey());
            System.out.println(me.getValue());
            sorted.put(me.getKey().toString(),  me.getValue().toString());

       }
        System.out.println(sorted);

        return null;
    }   
}
```

Here is the o/p :

```
1
hii
7
hii
10
hiiuu
15
hii
21
hii
{21=hii, 10=hiiuu, 1=hii, 7=hii, 15=hii}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't need the last inch of performance, you can solve this rather directly, without an extra step to sort the map, by using `SortedMap`:

```
Map<String,String> result = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparingInt(Integer::parseInt));
```

If you are among the unfortunate bunch who are still being denied access to Java 8, you'll have to implement the `Comparator` in long-hand:

```
new TreeMap<>(new Comparator<String,String> { public int compare(String a, String b) {
  return Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(a), Integer.parseInt(b));
}});
```

The above approach works only under the assumption that all keys are parseable integers. If that is not the case, then you won't be able to use the `SortedMap` directly, but transform your original map into it, filtering out the unparseable keys.

Comment: I am not sure how to use it .

Comment: You just put your stuff into it, and when you want the sorted keys, just use `result.keySet()` and it will be in order.

Comment: Ok , But i am getting an error here `Integer::parseInt` , `Integer cannot be resolved to a variable` .

Comment: You are not on Java 8, then. In that case you cannot use the method reference and need to write out the full implementation of `Comparator` as an anonymous class instance.

Comment: But OP is putting in some non-integer `String`s as keys (into `result`, though not into the second `Map` he was creating). Surely this will give exceptions in the `Comparator` when it tries to call `Integer.parseInt()` on something that isn't parseable?

Comment: @chiastic-security Surely it will... OP has an empty catch-block, which basically filters out such non-numeric entries. If he has such a mixed map, he'll have to do the filtering explicitly first. using the Streams API this would be rather simple to do, but unfortunately OP doesn't have access to it.

Comment: No, OP is calling his `sortByKeys()`, which traps such exceptions and doesn't put the non-numeric keys into his second `Map`. But you're suggesting replacing the *first* `Map` (called `result`), which is rather different: he's now going to get an exception when he calls `result.put("error","10")` right near the beginning of his code.

Comment: @chiastic-security You seem to have repeated my statement in different words. OP has an empty-catch block in `sortByKeys` which achieves the filtering. To imitate this with my approach you would have your original `HashMap` and have some code which transfers entries one by one to the `SortedMap`, filtering by key. This loop would still be a one-liner.

Comment: OK, maybe I misunderstood what you had in mind. You've called it `result`, so I thought you were suggesting just replacing the original and ditching the second `Map`. But yes, this would be a nice place to use streams.

Comment: @chiastic-security You were right about my answer: I did not take into account the filtering there. I took it into account only here in the comments. I could make the answer clearer in that respect.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the `Map` you're putting them into is a `HashMap`, which isn't sorted. There's no guarantee of the ordering of results you'll get out of the `HashMap`, even if you put them in in the right order.

(And calling it `sorted` doesn't change anything :) )

Answer (score 1):

You print 2 **different** maps and not the same: you iterate over and print the entries of `newMap` map, and at the end you print `sorted` map.

You see the sorted entries printed because you iterate over your sorted `newMap`.

Then you print the `sorted` map which is **unsorted** (despite by its name). You print a different map instance.

Print this:

```
System.out.println(newMap); // This is the instance of the sorted "TreeMap"
```

Comment: Yes that is working . But I want the sorted Map (newMap) in <String,String> format . Which is now <Integer,String> . So I tried to loop through .

Comment: But `sorted` is a `HashMap` which is not even sorted, but even if you would use `TreeMap<String, String>` it cannot do what you want because the lexicographical order of `String`s is different from the natural order of numbers even if the `String`s contain numbers: `"2"` is **greater** than `"11"` even though `2` is **less** than `11`.

Comment: Yes I can see the issue.